# Multiplication of Matrix Properties - bi-symmetric, symmetric and anti-symmetric

Tags: matrices

Once again, can the great maths minds here please give a hand to explain or solve this problem. Much appreciated!

How can you prove that a bi-symmetric matrix multiplied by symmetrical vector will give me a symmetrical vector? 
Vice versa, a bi-symmetric matrix multiplied by anti-symmetrical vector will give me an anti-symmetrical vector?

Is there a way to solve it without using symbolic examples?

Comment: What is a symmetric vector?

Comment: What I meant to say is a symmetrical vector, $v=[a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_3 a_2 a_1]^T$. As for an anti-symmetrical vector $v=[a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 -a_3 -a_2 -a_1]^T$. Not sure if that is the sensible term for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J$ be the (as [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix) calls it) exchange matrix 
\[
  J = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\\
                      0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\\
                        &   & \vdots &\\\
                      0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\\
                      1 & 0 & \cdots & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
I assume that you call $v \in K^n$ *symmetric* if $Jv = v$ and anti-symmetric if $Jv = -v$, right?

Now let $A \in \mathrm{Mat}(n, K)$ bisymmetric, that is $JA = AJ$ and $A^T = A$. If $v \in K^n$ is symmetic, then 
\[
   J(Av) = JAv = AJv = Av 
\]
so $Av$ is symmetric, if $Jv = -v$, then 
\[
  J(Av) = AJv = A(-v) = -Av.
\]
Note, that we didn't use $A^T = A$ (i. e. $A$ being symmetric).

Comment: Thank you martini! Your definition is brilliant, clean and simple! Million of thanks~